# Angular main js file truncated?

Tags: javascript, angular, webstorm

I have an Angular 7 application that was working fine a few minutes ago.  It is still working on the local host using ng serve, but I did ng build --prod to build the production build and uploaded it to the server.  When I go to it on the server it is blank and gives me an error in the console *Unexpected end of input*.

I looked at it and the main.21e...86.js file is being truncated and that's where it shows the error.  The file is minified by the Angular build process so it's all one very long line.

Here is the output of the build:

```
Date: 2019-08-22T18:10:34.457Z
Hash: 60984d51912589979e3b
Time: 155732ms
chunk {0} runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.21e3c2279d182c22c8a6.js (main) 1.88 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.3bfd66addbd0d2814591.js (polyfills) 41 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.1ca72067a91cb35b9ca1.css (styles) 482 kB [initial] [rendered]
```

Here is a direct link to the js file: https://revolutiondesign.biz/apps/portal/main.21e3c2279d182c22c8a6.js.  What's weird is that I have looked at the local file as well as the one on the server and it ends with `o.subscribeToArray(t))}}},[[0,0]]]);` (i.e. it looks like a valid js file) but what is coming back from either the direct opening in a browser or the request viewed through dev tools ends with `t.prototype.useRelativePosition=function(t){re` which is obviously not valid.

Can anyone help?  What is causing this file to truncate like that and more important what can I do about it?  I have tried a rebuild, reload, clear cache, multiple browsers, restart the editing program I'm using (WebStorm), re-upload... Nothing seems to change this.

**EDIT**

Here is the actual page link:
https://revolutiondesign.biz/apps/portal/

Comment: what server and browser? truncating should work fine. my error is `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation: Function must be called on an object of type StorageArea
    at content.js:21`

Comment: Chrome, server is hosted on cloudflare...  I edited the question to include the page link (could probably infer it from the script link but just in case).  So you don't get an 'unexpected end of input' on that page?

Comment: unreplicable for me, file is not being truncated at all

Comment: ?? that's really strange.  I tried Chrome on my machine and on my phone as well as FireFox on my machine all with the same result...

Comment: Were you looking at that page or did you copy the script somewhere else?  I don't have a content.js nor do I have a 'StorageArea' object (though that could be internal Angular or a referenced library, I'm not sure).

Comment: Ops, that was an adblocker, your file is fine and being read correctly. IN ONE CHUNK.

Comment: How do I break it into multiple chunks?

Comment: but why would You? it's small

Comment: Sorry, I thought that's what you were suggesting, I'm pretty new to web development still and Angular.  So you are reading the full file and see the login page, etc.?

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me: `Sorry, we don't recognize those credentials. Forgot your password?`, so scripts are working ok, and no error.

Comment: So weird... OK well that's good, kind of...  Now just need to figure out why it's not working for me.  Will try some more devices I guess?  Also will talk to web host...  Thank you.

Comment: YW ..................................

Comment: aaaand, now it's back without me doing anything else... has to be some type of caching issue on the host side.

Comment: maybe try CTRL+F5 in your browser? are you using some VPN or proxy?

Comment: I did that many times and it didn't help before.  I'm thinking this is something to do with CloudFlare caching but I"m trying to check with the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that comes across this, the issue ended up being related to CloudFlare caching as far as I can tell.  It seems like I refreshed the page before the cache was fully updated (at least that's the best I can figure) and it ended up with only part of the file on the cache that I was referencing.  When this has happened again later I was able to go into CloudFlare settings and clear all caches and it came back normally.  I also now try to wait a few minutes after uploading the new files and then do an empty cache and hard reload from my browser and haven't had it happen in quite a while.